# Exercise: Implement an abstract class

Tags: c#

So i'm following a C# beginner tutorial at dotnetcademy.net and one of the exercises is to Implement an abstract class.

and the goals are:
1. Create a class named SpaceStation that is abstract
2. On that abstract class, add a abstract method called FireLaser
3. Create a derived class called DeathStar that implements the FireLaser method to write "Pew pew" to the Console followed by a new line.

the code that you start with is:

```
using System;

// Implement your classes here

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

---

so i wrote this but it says on return that "Since 'DeathStar.FireLaser()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"
but i don't know what else to write, i've tried multiple other things

```
using System;

// Implement your classes here
public abstract class SpaceStation
{
    public abstract void FireLaser();   
}

public class DeathStar : SpaceStation
{
    public override void FireLaser()
    {
        return  Console.WriteLine("Pew pew");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

So if anybody has a solution so i can reflect it on what i wrote that would be nice or if anybody can say what it should be instead.

Comment: Remove `return`.

Comment: I have modified your code to follow standard C# indention patterns. I suggest you adopt this style, it makes the program easier to read.

Comment: Omit the `return`, simply use { Console.WriteLine(...); }

Comment: As a rule Void methods don't return. Remove the Return from the FireLaser method in the DeathStar class and see what happens

Comment: Just remove the `return` statement.  `void` methods don't return anything.  (Does `Console.WriteLine()` even return anything?)  You *can* have a single `return;` line by itself in a `void` method, to return from the method.  But it can't carry a value.  Note: None of this has anything to do with abstract classes.  This is just basic method structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `return` statement from the overridden `FireLaser` method:

```
public class DeathStar : SpaceStation
{
    public override void FireLaser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pew pew");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh such a simple mistake. Thank you so much though!

Answer (score 0):

A method `marked` as void does not return anything. The `return` keyword is usually used to return a result from a method. Therefore it usually does not make sense in a void method. Removing the `return` keyword from your statement will resolve your compiler error.

```
public class DeathStar : SpaceStation
{
    public override void FireLaser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Pew pew");
    }
}
```

Note that the return keyword *can* be used in a void method to end the method. However, its usage is generally discouraged because it can result code that returns from multiple places and this can be confusing. When used in this manner, you still do not return an actual value. `return` would be the only part of the statement. Consider the following code:

```
public void ProcessSomeWork(SomeWork work)
{
    if(work.IsCompleted)
    {
        return;
    }

    work.DoSomething();
    DoSomethingElseToWork(work);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailled explaination i really appreciate it!